# Exceptions (array index out bounds exception)

Tags: java, exception

can someone please help me with this. i have to:

- Create an array with 100 randomly chosen integers.
- Create a text field to enter an array index and another textfield to display the array element at the specified index.
- Create a Show Element button to cause thearray element to be displayed. If the specified index is out ofbounds, display the message Out of Bound in the designated area.

this is what i have so far, can someone please tell be what else i have to add.

any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;   

public class showindexextends Applet implements ActionListener
{  int [] number =new int[100];
   Random r= new Random();
   Label indexlabel = new Label(" index:");
   TextField indexfield = new TextField(10);

   Label valuelabel = new Label("value:");
   TextField valuefield = new TextField(10);

   Button showButton = new Button ("Show Element");
   public void init()
      { int i;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
          number[i]=r.nextInt(1000)+1;  // random number between 1 and 1000 
        add(indexlabel);
        add(indexfield);
        add(valuelabel);
        add(valuefield);
        add(showButton);

        showButton.addActionListener(this);
        valuefield.setEditable(false);

      }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)     
      { String inputString;
        int num;
        inputString=indexfield.getText();
        num=Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        if(num>99 ||num<0)
          valuefield.setText("Outof Bound");
        else      
          valuefield.setText(number[num]+"");

      }
}
```

Comment: where do you get your exception?

Comment: What's not working or what can't you work out?

Comment: What is your question here? Your code already does whatever you mentioned.

Comment: for some reason its not complying

Comment: Not compiling or not complying? Though I guess if it's not compiling, it's definitely not complying.

Comment: What error do you get when compiling?

Comment: Where do you specify your add method?

Answer (score 1):

The class declaration is incorrect:

```
public class showindexextends Applet implements ActionListener
```

should probably be :

```
public class showindexextends extends Applet implements ActionListener
```

You should practice reading the error messages from the compiler and use the clues it gives you to track down the error in your program.  It also helps to write your code in an IDE with syntax highlighting.  Check out [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: should probably be ShowIndex... :)